# Is there a way to use custom executor in Hazelcast?

Tags: java, hazelcast, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, executor

It is possible to configure custom executor using `ExecutorConfig`, e.g.:

```
Config config = new Config();
config.getExecutorConfig("my-custom-executor").setPoolSize(40).setName("my-executor");
```

This will finally create some `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` child.

But how can I specify customly created `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` implementation as some named executor in Hazelcast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a custom `j.u.c.ExecutorService` managed by Hazelcast is not possible at the moment (current latest GA version is *3.12.5* and *4.0* is about to be released). All executors share the same cached thread-pool using separate task queues per custom executor (see [CachedExecutorServiceDelegate](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/internal/util/executor/CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java)). And this shared thread pool is an instance of `j.u.c.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

I think it should be fairly easy to add this as a new feature. You can create an issue at [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/new/choose) or better send a pull request with an implementation.